# Confusion over usage of $N(\varepsilon)$ Notation in the Definition of Slowly Oscillating

Tags: real-analysis, statistics, notation

Let $ (X,d) $ be a metric space. A sequence $(x_{n}) $ of points in $X$ is called  slowly oscillating if, for any given $ \varepsilon > 0 $, there exists $\delta= \delta(\varepsilon)> 0 $ and $ N = N(\varepsilon) $ such that
$ d(x_{m},x_{n})< \varepsilon $ if  $ n \ge N(\varepsilon)  $ and $ n \le m \le (1 + \delta)n  $.
What is $N(\varepsilon)$?

Comment: I think it show that $N$ depends on $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

$N(\varepsilon)$ is just a constant (most likely) in $\Bbb{N}$ which depends on $\varepsilon$. This notation of $N(\varepsilon)$ is used to emphasize the dependence.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: No problem. If this answers your question be sure to accept it using the check mark.